# Use 2 JQuery versions

Tags: jquery, conflict, versions

I'm an author in Themeforest, Today I got a message from Envato telling me that I have to use the latest version of jQuery to get my html template approved, but when I use the latest version The camera slider by ( http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/ ) disappears.
What Can I do ?
Please I need Help 
Thanks

Comment: `jquery noConflict()`.

Comment: Use latest jQuery version with jQuery Migrate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.noConflict( true )`

```
 <script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

For more information about jquery `noConflict();` refer [**THIS**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)